# How to understand Smullyan's notion of weakly adequate Gödel numbering

Tags: logic, incompleteness

I was working on Smullyan's *Diagonalization and Self-Reference* (1994). In Chapter 9 (p.168), he defines the notion of a *weakly adequate* Gödel numbering as follows:

> Let $\mathscr{L}$ be a first-order language and $g$ be a Gödel numbering. $g$ is weakly adequate if the following two conditions hold.
>
> 1. There is a relation $C(x,y,z)$ expressible in $\mathscr{L}$ such that for any expressions $X$ and $Y$ with respective Gödel numbers $x$ and $y$ the relation $C(x,y,z)$ holds if and only if $z$ is the Gödel number of $XY$.
> 2. There is a relation $N(x,y)$ such that for any *Gödel number* $x$, the relation $N(x,y)$ holds if and only if $y=\bar{x}$.

The first condition seems okay. To put it roughly, it means that the syntactic relation "$Z$ is the concatenation of $X$ and $Y$" is expressible in $\mathscr{L}$, where $Z$ is an expression with the Gödel number $z$.

But I have a trouble understanding the second condition. Here is why. Smullyan uses $\bar{x}$ to refer to the numeral denoting $x$ in $\mathscr{L}$. But what does it mean for a number to be a symbol? So it seems to me that the condition 2 should be rephrased as

> 2'. There is a relation $N(x,y)$ such that for any *Gödel number* $x$, the relation $N(x,y)$ holds if and only if $y$ is the Gödel number of $\bar{x}$.

Am I missing something here? Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3):

See page 76 :

> For any natural number $n$, by $\overline n$ we mean the symbol $0$ followed by
>   $n$ accents [i.e. the term referring to the $n$-th successor of $0$], and we refer to $\overline n$ as the *numeral* designating $n$. [e.g., $0''''$ (sometimes used : $SSSS0$ ) is the numeral designating the number $4$.]

Having said that, IMO you are right; compare page 85 :

> there is a function $\text {num}(x)$ such that for every number $x$, the number  $\text {num}(x)$ is the $g$-number of the numeral $\overline x$.

If so, I agree with your proposed correction :

> ... the relation $\text N(x,y)$ holds if and only if $y$ is the $g$-number of the *numeral* $\overline x$.

Relations like $C(x,y,z)$ are "numerical" objects: they hold between numbers.

The trick of "arithmetization" is to achieve self-reference showing how to *express* or *represent* numerical relations with formulas of the language.

Comment: I guess, my point is that precisely because $\bar{n}$ is a term (a symbol in $\mathscr{L}$) we cannot simply say $y=\bar{x}$ in the given definition of a weakly adequate Gödel numbering.

Comment: I am not so sure that the relation $N(x,y)$ is expressible in $\mathscr{L}$.  I found it interesting that Smullyan does not show (as far as I can see) that $N(x,y)$ is expressible in $\mathscr{L}$ (under a reasonable Gödel numbering), and I was hoping to know whether $N(x,y)$ is indeed expressible. The quote from p.56 defines what it is for a formula to express a property, or represent the set of numbers with a property.  So it does not seem to show that $N(x,y)$ is expressible.

Comment: @MauroAllegranza I have to wonder just how many books on logic you own, given how many exact references you are able to provide.  It is amazing.

Comment: @DanielV - mainly electronic copies (pdf, djvu). Unfortunately, I've no more enough time ahead of me to read thm all :-)